# Download data into excel from r shiny table created with reactable

Tags: r, excel, shiny, download, reactable

I have a shiny dashboard where the tables are created with the `reactable` package. I have simple and nested tables and as far as I can see, there is only a download option for csv:

```r
library(htmltools)
library(fontawesome)

data <- MASS::Cars93[1:15, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price")]

htmltools::browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$button(
      tagList(fontawesome::fa("download"), "Download as CSV"),
      onclick = "Reactable.downloadDataCSV('cars-download-table', 'cars.csv')"
    ),

    reactable(
      data,
      searchable = TRUE,
      defaultPageSize = 5,
      elementId = "cars-download-table"
    )
  )
)
```

I want to create one Excel download file with the following attributes:

- the tables to download are selected via a `checkboxGroupInput`
- one Excel sheet per selected item
- the name of the sheet corresponds to selected item
- if there is more than one table in the selected item, all those tables should be in one sheet (divided by some empty rows)
- some captions (read from another file) should be inserted above the tables

The problem is, that I want to use the data shown in the `reactable` (e.g. the selected columns), therefore I can not use the raw data. Is there some kind of package I can use?
So far, I only have a slow solution where I put the `reactable` into an additional variable before I render the table and then I read the data from this variable and use the package `openxlsx` to write the Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a clue. You can get the current state of the table with `Reactable.getState`, and the current display is in the field `sortedData`. This is demonstrated by the app below.

```r
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(jsonlite)

registerInputHandler(
  "xx",
  function(data, ...){
    fromJSON(toJSON(data))
  },
  force = TRUE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      7,
      tags$button(
        "Get data",
        onclick = '
          var state = Reactable.getState("cars");
          Shiny.setInputValue("dat:xx", state.sortedData);
        '
      ),
      reactableOutput("cars")
    ),
    column(
      5,
      verbatimTextOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$cars <- renderReactable({
    reactable(MASS::Cars93[, 1:5], filterable = TRUE)
  })

  output$data <- renderPrint({
    input$dat
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

Here is an example of downloading the current display:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(reactable)
library(jsonlite)

registerInputHandler(
  "xx",
  function(data, ...){
    fromJSON(toJSON(data))
  },
  force = TRUE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  br(),
  conditionalPanel(
    "false", # always hide the download button, because we will trigger it 
    downloadButton("downloadData") # programmatically with shinyjs
  ),
  actionButton(
    "dwl", "Download", class = "btn-primary",
    onclick = paste0(
      'var state = Reactable.getState("cars");',
      'Shiny.setInputValue("dat:xx", state.sortedData);'
    )
  ),
  br(),
  reactableOutput("cars")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$cars <- renderReactable({
    reactable(MASS::Cars93[, 1:5], filterable = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$dat, {
    runjs("$('#downloadData')[0].click();")
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      openxlsx::write.xlsx(input$dat, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I have just one problem left: I have nested tables and `Reactable.getState` only returns data if the row was extended (which it is not by default). Is there something to change this behavior? Here is an example for a nested table: `data <- as.data.frame(unique(MASS::Cars93[, 1]))
    reactable(data, details = function(index){
      part_data <- MASS::Cars93[MASS::Cars93[, 1] == data[index, 1], 2:5]
      htmltools::div(style = "padding: 1rem",
                     reactable(part_data, outlined = TRUE, elementId = paste0('cars', index)))},  filterable = TRUE)`

Comment: Together with ```Reactable.toggleAllRowsExpanded("cars", true);       Reactable.toggleAllRowsExpanded("cars", false);```for nested tables I can get all the data.